# float to string conversion in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am converting float to string using this method

```
    -(NSString*)FloatToStr:(float)floatVal
      {
            NSString *string;
            string=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.02f",floatVal];
            return string;
      }

    float x=15.625;
    NSLog(@"c==>%@",[self FloatToStr:x]);

    //Output:15.62
```

it gives the 15.62, but i want 15.63.

Comment: use `float roundval = ceil(string);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are truncating the number to two decimals positions. If you want to round to two decimals, make this before to convert to string.

```
-(NSString*)FloatToStr:(float)floatVal
{
NSString *string;
string=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.02f",roundf(floatVal*100)/100];
return string;
}
```

Comment: Better yet - use `NSNumberFormatter` so the value is properly rounded and it is properly formatted for the user's locale.